# Windows Forms: WebBrowser - access local files

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, winforms, internet-explorer

What `CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled` feature are required to access local files over ajax in Forms WebBrowser component (W10, mshtml v11, Trident)? Assuming `Localmachine_Lockdown` is 0 and JS is working, but jQuery AJAX fails with IE error 2147024891 "Access Denied". Desired behaviour: like Chrome with "`--allow-file-access-from-files`" flag. CefSharp & Co are no option, unfortunatelly.

Use case: imagine a large JS-App (AMD modules, JSON-configs, etc) you want to put in your WF application, local security policy prohibits using of a simple web server and there is no way to install a web server somewhere in the local network, no Internet connection available. Yup, that's bad.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not manage to find anything that would allow JS access local files in WinForms WebBrowser under Windows10 (and I have tried everything).

So, I have eliminated the problem itself - I have bundled my JS-App into 3 files (html, css and js) so that it doesn't need to load modules anymore. All JSON-configs and language files are moved into WCF Services and accessed just like all other data requests (through a method binded to windows.external with "ObjectForScripting"). From now on the App is working same way it does on a web server.